# Out-of-class definition of function of specialized inner class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, template-specialization

Please consider the following ill-formed program:

```
struct S {
    template<class T> struct J { };
};

template<>
struct S::J<void> {
    void f();
};

template<>
void S::J<void>::f() {} // ERROR

$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
no function template matches function template specialization 'f'

$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
template-id ‘f<>’ for ‘void S::J<void>::f()’ does not match any template declaration
```

Why doesn't the definition of `f` compile?  How do I define the function `f` correctly in the above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The clang error is very helpful here:

```
no function template matches function template specialization 'f'
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The syntax you're using is for a function template. But `f` isn't a function template, it's just a function. To define it, we don't need the `template` keyword:

```
void S::J<void>::f() {}
```

At this point, `S::J<void>` is just another class, so this is no different than your standard:

```
void Class::method() { }
```

You'd only need `template` if you were defining a member function of a template, for instance:

```
template <typename T>
void S::J<T>::g() { }
```

or a member function template:

```
template <typename T>
void S::J<void>::h<T>() { }
```

Comment: "*You'd only need `template` if you were defining a member function of a template*" Or a template member function.